# Showing error off focus - Validation jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How could I show my error when the user clicks out of the input box etc?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    $("#quote").validate({
        rules:{
            companyName:{
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        }
    });
etc etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow this took me WAY too long to figure out.

Short answer: `input type="input"` should be `input type="text"`.

Then this will work:

```
$("#quote").validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) {
         $(element).valid();
    },
    rules:{
        companyName:{
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I could load this error into a specific error div?

Comment: errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.siblings("label"));
                }

Comment: Perhaps edit your answer to include the code in your comment... [see the OP's follow-up question based on your comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200250/jquery-setting-a-validation-error-box-with-two-classes).