# jQuery Setting a validation error box with two classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an with my code and I have one particular `textarea` that I am using the main `.error` class and another `.textAreaError` that places the error box were I want it but I am unsure how I would configure the textarea error to load in this specific box.

[From a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151646/594235) I was given the following jQuery line `function(error, element) { error.appendTo(element.siblings("label")); }` but I am unsure how to work it into the code below.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    onfocusout: true,
    $("#quote").validate({
        rules:{
            companyName:{
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML:**

`<div class="error textAreaError">Error Here</div>`

Comment: That's invalid code.  You can't just have `onfocusout: true,` sitting all by itself.  It's an optional parameter for the plugin so it needs to be with the other optional parameters.  Also, look a lot more carefully at [the code **and comments** in the accepted answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10151646/594235) for the full answer.  Hint:  `errorPlacement:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) for the validate plugin, it looks like you can control the position of the error with the errorPlacement argument which uses function(error, element). The code would look something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    $("#quote").validate({
        onfocusout: true,
        rules:{
            companyName:{
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.is("textarea"))
                error.appendTo(".textAreaError");
            else
                error.appendTo(".generalError");
        }
    });
});
```

You'd have to give the general error box the generalError class. Or, give the error boxes id's and refer to those instead (e.g. "#textAreaError" and "#generalError").

Comment: The way I see it, the main question was where to apply that function. But I was working on a code sample anyways...

Comment: The OP needs to see it as he totally ignored a critical part of code contained in [the comment in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10151646/594235).

Comment: How could I do more then one appendTo?  I have .error as the general error box and a specialized one for the textarea

Comment: See updated answer, which now checks the element's type and then either adds the error to the textAreaError or generalError box.